# Actionbar title and subtitle alignment and textSize in fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am using actionbar and displaying some title and subtitle of the actionbar. I want the size of subtitle to be smaller than the title.  And also I have a logo icon in left. So how should I adjust the alignment.

There's an another fragment in which I am using back button as home button. So, I also want to reduce the space between the back button and the Title of actionbar.

I tried using this code. But it didn't help.

UserListFragment.java

```
 View viewActionBar = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.actionbar_layout, null);
        ActionBar.LayoutParams params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,Gravity.CENTER);

TextView textviewTitle = (TextView) viewActionBar.findViewById(R.id.mytext);
textviewTitle.setText("DemoIosAppDoctor"+"\n"+"Doctor");
actionBar.setCustomView(viewActionBar, params);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
}
```

actionbar_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:id="@+id/mytext"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-2dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

To completely customise Actionbar, you should define Toolbar in design XML and add you own component there. and, then use like this

```
Toolbar tb = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(tb);
```

Use XML like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView" />


            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Note: You have to set this activity theme as NoActionBar like this:

```
<activity
            android:name=".YourActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".index.IndexActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

And theme like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: It gives error in setSupportActionBar and findViewById

Comment: If you are using support library than, you have to use setSupportActionBar.  Else use setActionBar

Comment: You should follow this.  https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html#utility

Comment: Hey Milind,
The solution worked, but I have one more issue. I updated it in question. Please check and let me know if you have any solution. This solution doesn't worked for that. 

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you have your own custom layout for ActionBar now, so you can Design anything as per your requirement like you design other layouts in Android.
You can even put TextView for Title and SubTitle and set their TextSize rather than using ActionBar's default Title and SubTitle